# Objective-C Search NSArray for String?

Tags: iphone, arrays, find

I have an array of strings.

How might I be able to figure out what index a string is in a array?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`-[NSArray indexOfObject:]`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABDHGFB)

Comment: wow? That was... Simple. Hahah I'll give it a try and get back to you.

Comment: This is only going to work if you have a reference to the same string object that was put in the array. Not just a string that has the same value.

Comment: It will work when using `indexOfObject:@"Some string"`! `indexOfObject:` uses `isEqual:` on the objects in the array, and `NSString's` implementation of `isEqual:` tests the value of the string, not the pointer ;)

Comment: I'm getting an error about the index being out of range when I try to use the value returned from indexOfObject: It says that the returned index is something crasy like 201341023 or something... My array is literally 3 things long.

Comment: That number is actually `NSNotFound`, which is returned when the object was not found in the array.

Comment: > indexOfObject: uses isEqual:

Hmm, good info. I actually did not know that!

Answer (score 1):

Though very old but this question comes quite high in google search. Here is a version in using block,

```
- (void)testSearch
{
    NSArray *hashAlgorithms = @[@"SHA1", @"SHA2", @"SHA256", @"SHA384", @"SHA512"];
    NSString *searchFor = @"SHA384";
    __block NSInteger index = NSNotFound;
    [hashAlgorithms enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id alg, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([alg compare:searchFor options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame) {
            NSLog(@"Found: %@", searchFor);
            *stop = YES;
            index = idx;
        } else {
            NSLog(@"NOT Equal: %@", alg);
        }
    }];

    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        NSLog(@"Not found. %li", (long)index);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Found at: %li", (long)index);
    }
}
```