# NSIndexSet from Array

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enumerate NSArray using blocks to find and store all indexe's of all NSStrings in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386094/enumerate-nsarray-using-blocks-to-find-and-store-all-indexes-of-all-nsstrings-i)

I am trying to get a `NSIndexSet` from an Array of objects. My question is related to getting the indexSet.

Can I get an `indexSet` by searching for a class using `introspection`? i.e. I have an array of numbers and strings. I want an index set of all the strings in the array.

Comment: You'll need to be more clear here. What is "an index set of all the strings in the array?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSIndexSet *indexSet = [myArray indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    return [obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]];
}];
```