# Most optimal way to check if string == "(any of multiple strings)" {}

Tags: ios, swift

I need a fast optimal way to create if else statement that checks string vs multiple strings

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ANY OF MULTIPLE STRINGS 'x1'-'x9'"{
        let JVC = segue.destinationViewController as VC3
        JVC.betSource = segue.identifier!     
    } else {
        let KVC = segue.destinationViewController as VC2
        KVC.source = segue.identifier!
    }
```

**Should I use an Array:string, do 9 different if/else or something completely different?**

I don't know what would run the code most optimally. Please advise

Comment: try [String search in string array in objective c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802171/string-search-in-string-array-in-objective-c)

Comment: this is for swift not Objective c

Comment: just convert to swift

Comment: if i knew how to i would, I don't know objective C. I am teaching myself Swift

Comment: so you should read this https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/containsObject:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most optimal way is to make an array of the possible matches and then use `contains` to find a specific string in that array.

```
let array = ["a", "b", "c"]

if contains(array, segue.identifier) {
    // String found in array
}
```

Comment: ty very much, one last question is it more optimal to state `array` at top of VC1 or in the prepareForSegue that way the array is only created when segue is used?

Comment: I would keep it in the prepareForSegue so it isn't cluttering up the rest of your class and it isn't allocated until it is being used

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`switch`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID129) in this case:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    switch segue.identifier! {
    case "x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6", "x7", "x8", "x9":
        let JVC = segue.destinationViewController as VC3
        JVC.betSource = segue.identifier!
    default:
        let KVC = segue.destinationViewController as VC2
        KVC.source = segue.identifier!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9"
if(str.rangeOfString(segue.identifier)) 
let JVC = segue.destinationViewController as VC3
    JVC.betSource = segue.identifier!     
} else {
    let KVC = segue.destinationViewController as VC2
    KVC.source = segue.identifier!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Following Code .......

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) 
{
    var string = "ANY OF MULTIPLE STRINGS 'x1'-'x9'"

    if string.rangeOfString(segue.identifier) != nil 
    {
        let JVC = segue.destinationViewController as VC3
        JVC.betSource = segue.identifier!     
    }
    else
    {
        let KVC = segue.destinationViewController as VC2
        KVC.source = segue.identifier!
    }
}
```

Comment: this would work I'm guessing but I plan to add more else statements for other segue unwinds. ty